# Drop-down empty selection from the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I work with a JavaScript app and populate the drop-down menu with a `JSON` list.

```
                        $("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text(""));
                        $.each(wallets, function (index, wallet) {

                            if (selectedCurrency === wallet["currency"].toString().trim()) {
                                $("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text(wallet["address"]));
                            }
                        })
```

The UI looks like this,

[image]

If I select the empty item (like in the picture), I would like to print `empty` in the console. Otherwise, I want to print the address value. My intention is to write more code, but, this is where I would like to get started. The code I have,

```
$("#address").change(function () {

        if($(this).val()===""){
            console.log('empty');
        }
        
        else{
            console.log($(this).val());
        }
}
```

However, it only prints 1 in the console and can't distinguish between the empty bar and the address in concern. If I use `console.log("The value is " + $(this).text());` inside the `change` function, it prints every info all together in the console,

`The value is mp51mPC38Wtcmybdyd9MPEB2bKnw6eYbCsmqXjM7Mmg6B5LWMad7mHJi339ddaj7xXdBmvXxP1GmXXKojWQJKjgeoASnXVNXCS47z6n41jE2BKKpV6LsPb7dDdStjtuJf1FrYvMMmw1jtrWU5DADxvNR421MKFW1fposgzVMBymnzcZVF4jtZtGAggM5GuLog3Y5o52Mx4xMmq5Rgggfgy2TiRsvtcGm3rxx12R8XbYi9omkdt7ouyJnDXUp4LzdRSRP3ZhU57gUDKy6n2F2QEKk6Fqqk2yMTope5MYp1RtpT949kemrkdfp6qoVN3YiyJhq6nXPvgr3f7YpkS9j`

The JSON data I have is something like,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "BTC",
    "address": "mp51mPC38Wtcmybdyd9MPEB2bKnw6eYbCs",
    "currency": "Bitcoin"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "BTC",
    "address": "mqXjM7Mmg6B5LWMad7mHJi339ddaj7xXdB",
    "currency": "Bitcoin"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "BTC",
    "address": "mvXxP1GmXXKojWQJKjgeoASnXVNXCS47z6",
    "currency": "Bitcoin"
  }

   // some more data 
]
```

What the issue here? My guess is I do something wrong to append the data to the drop-down list and needs to be changed.

I can provide more info if required ....

Comment: you set the value `1` for empty text `$("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text(""));` change this value to empty.

Comment: .text to .html() // $("#address").append($('<option></option>').val(wallet.id).html(wallet.address);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the value `1` to `""` in first option.

```
$("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "").text(""));

$.each(wallets, function (index, wallet) {
    if (selectedCurrency === wallet["currency"].toString().trim()) {
          $("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text(wallet["address"]));
      }
});
```

check this example.

```js
$("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "").text(""));
$("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "1").text("123"));
$("#address").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", "2").text("456"));

 
 $("#address").change(function () {

        if($(this).val()===""){
            console.log('empty');
        }

        else{
            console.log($(this).val());
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="address">
</select>
```